# Read-only Slack channel (except threads)

Tags: slack

I want to have channel where users can ONLY send messages in threads. Is it possible? I tried with [Stacktodo](https://www.stacktodo.com/tools/block), but I did not found a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Slack allows to restrict write access to channels, but only for the #general channel. There you can restrict access to admins only or even owners only.

If you want to restrict write access to other channels or use a more granular access list you need to use a Slack app like Stacktodo (with their so called Block Bot) or build your own Slack bot that provides that additional functionality.

Please contact the support team from Stacktodo if you can not get it to work.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to BLOCK sending messages in channels except threads. I have channel #easter-eggs where we discussing about these but I want to have these discussions only in threads (for the purity of this channel). I think my description is clear?

Comment: @SzymonŻak Sorry, I missed the part about threads in your question. Pretty sure that you can make a bot that blocks all new messages except threads, but I am not aware of an app that does it. And since this is a forum for programmers, you might want to take your question to https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it existed in 2017 but yes, you can do it in the channel settings->posting permissions.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPclo.png)

Answer (score 0):

2023 Update - You can do this now if you have a Business Plus plan. Free and Pro plans you only have granular permissions on `General` channel

[image: slack plans october 2023]